# R Loop to reference multiple dataframes

Tags: r, loops, rstudio

I'm trying to create a loop to pull data from multiple dataframes in R and then rbind them into one dataframe.
The dataframes are all named identically, with an increment appended at the end (split1, split2, split3...) to differentiate.

Each dataframe contains a list of numbers, which I'm looking to append to the URL.

The loop I've built so far is as follows:

```
requester_url <- "https://example.url/users/show_many/ids="
for(i in 1:7 {
  splitname <- paste0('split',i)
  requester_ids <- paste0(splitname, collapse = ",")
  requester_url <-paste0(requester_url,requester_ids)
}
```

If I breakdown what I want the elements to do within the loop, this may be more helpful.
From the below section, I'd like to create create a new variable, which is the dataframe name with the increment applied.

```
splitname <- paste0('split',i)
```

I'd hope this would output 'split1, split2, split3...', which would then be referenced in the next part of the loop.

```
requester_ids <- paste0(splitname, collapse = ",")
```

This should extract the numbers contained with the looped dataframe name and collapse with commas separating the numbers. The collapse I know works, as I've used this multiple times outside of the loop.

And then finally, the last part of the loop should take the url variable and append all the id's pulled in the previous line and end as:
"https://example.url/users/show_many/ids=11111,22222,33333...."

I believe the problem is in the first line, where it is storing the dataframe name as a character, rather than a variable name.

I've been wracking my brain for the best of a day for how to solve this, but I'm very new to loops and this is beyond my skill level.

Comment: `splitname <- paste0('split',i)` will create only a single string within each iteration, therefore `requester_ids <- paste0(splitname, collapse = ",")` does nothing as there are no multiple strings to collapse.

Comment: That's a very good point. Do you have suggestion for how I would amend my loop to work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed the problem is using the name string of the tables, not the tables themselves. You just need 'get' to make your code working.

```
split1 <- 100:109
split2 <- 200:209
split3 <- 300:309
split4 <- 400:409
split5 <- 500:509
split6 <- 600:609
split7 <- 700:709
requester_url <- "https://example.url/users/show_many/ids="
for(i in 1:7) {
  splitname <- paste0('split',i)
  requester_ids <- paste0(get(splitname), collapse = ",")
  if (i>1) sep <- ',' else sep <- ''
  requester_url <- paste(requester_url,requester_ids,sep=sep)
}
```

But a better solution would be not doing any loop at all : first merge (rbind) the 7 datasets then collapse the result.

Comment: This worked perfectly, however I tweaked the if statement to suit my needs.

Just to clarify as to why I was using several datasets - the API I'm interacting from has a limit of 100 records, so the 7 datasets are actually a split from a larger dataset.
For this particular API call, there is no pagination, so it requires multiple calls with split datasets.